# Do I need to initialize AdMob twice when using two different AdMob plugins in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I have an app that shows three different ads (banner, interstitial and native), for banners and interstitials I'm using: [firebase_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob) and for native ads: [flutter_native_admob](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob), because the official plugin (the first one) doesn't support native ads.

But according to read_me they both needs to be initialized, do I need to initialize both to get ads working correctly?

```
await FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
_nativeAdmob.initialize(appID: Ads.appId);
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to initialize both plugins.

Comment: Can you answer the question and if possible explaining why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you need to initialize both plugins.**

- Because both plugins are using different code and both need to initialize their variables and classes for use in future.

```
_nativeAdmob.initialize(appID: "<Your Admob app ID>");
```

**&**

```
FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appId);
```